# Codename One: How to display a scaled image while maintaining the aspect ratio?

Tags: codenameone

**I'm trying to figure out to display an image (photo) supplied by the user (which may come in any size) in the highest quality while maintaining the aspect ratio.** (Photo supplied by user may have different width and height.)

I have the following code:

```
private Container prepareMainPhotoContainer(Image influencerMainPhoto) {
    if(influencerMainPhoto == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int deviceDisplayWidth = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
    int mainPhotoCurrentWidth = influencerMainPhoto.getWidth();
    int displayWidth = (int) (deviceDisplayWidth * 0.8);
    int mainPhotoWidth = mainPhotoCurrentWidth > displayWidth ? displayWidth : mainPhotoCurrentWidth;
    Image scaledInfluencerMainPhoto = influencerMainPhoto.scaled(mainPhotoWidth, -1);
    Container imageContainer = new Container();
    imageContainer.add(scaledInfluencerMainPhoto);
    return imageContainer;
}
```

According to the documentation, it says that the scaled method can accept -1, but it does not seem to work.

Also, it would be nice if the image can be centered on the screen.

Please help by providing some code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Image scaledInfluencerMainPhoto = influencerMainPhoto.scaled(mainPhotoWidth, -1);
```

Should work to set the width to `mainPhotoWidth` and preserve aspect ratio.  What results are you getting?